# How to subtract 2 UTC dates in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, utc

In my website i store User Visit `DateTime` information in sql server using **date** data Type.
for that i used  `UtcNow` in `C#` .

```
 visit_date = System.DateTime.UtcNow
```

Now  i want get the hours difference if same user visiting in my website so how can i subtract 2 UTC dates .I am using following way to get the diff in hour but it gives wrong hours difference.

```
TimeSpan timeDiff = System.DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract((DateTime)_Last_View.visit_date);
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code, but likly value in visit_date in not what you expect (assuming usage of timeDiff.TotalHours).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to get the Hours using the TotalHours on the resulting Timespan like:

```
TimeSpan interval = date2.Subtract(date1);
double Hours = interval.TotalHours;
```

Comment: +1. This is most likely reason - TimeSpan.Hours vs. TimeSpan.TotalHours (assuming data is correct).

Comment: Thanks ...I was using Hours Property instead of TotalHours .

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime dt2 = (DateTime)_Last_View;

TimeSpan ts = dt1.Subtract(dt2);

int seconds = ts.Seconds;
int minutes = ts.Minutes;
double hours = ts.TotalHours;
int days = ts.Days;
int days = ts.TotalDays;
int years = (int) (ts.Days / 365.25); // leap years included
```

Check this [Calculating Date Difference in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dipalchoksi/datediff_cs_dc09132006172429pm/datediff_cs_dc.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx):

```
double timeDiffTicks = System.DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - visit_date.Ticks;
double hours = (((timeDiffTicks / 10000)/1000) / 60)/60;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank .

It works

```
TimeSpan timeDiff = System.DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract((DateTime)_Last_View.visit_date);

            if (timeDiff.TotalHours > 24)
            {
            }
```

I was using `timeDiff.Hours` instead of `timeDiff.TotalHours`.